# Sticky/Fixed Menu Flickering on Scroll (CSS and jQuery Issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having this strange issue on Google Chrome only, when I scroll down on the following website, at some point there is a flicker which I cannot get rid of.

http://new.lovelife.one/

This uses Bridge Wordpress theme, and I have slightly modified the menu.  I have checked the jQuery file which adds the class on scroll, and also checked the CSS but cannot see exactly what the reason is!

Video to demonstrate the issue:

https://www.useloom.com/share/6d59405dc7174e14ba2ea026a4305f1e

Comment: It doesn't flicker on windows chrome for me.

Comment: Try incognito mode

Comment: That is very strange, I have reverted a piece of code which was added, please let me know if this still doesn't occur for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below style in your style sheet

```
header.centered_logo .logo_wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition:  all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition:  all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
}
.scrolled .logo_wrapper {
    display: none;
}
.header_bottom, header, .header_inner, .header_top_bottom_holder{
transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition:  all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition:  all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
}
```